# PhpStorm with PHPStan in Docker doesn't work

Tags: docker, phpstorm, phpstan

When using the System PHP interpreter for PHPStan, I get an error that the PHP version mismatches with the one being used in the Docker, see picture.

[image]

But when I set PHPStan to use the PHP interpreter inside the Docker container, I get an error "input device is not a TTY".

[image]

Anyone got any ideas how to get this running? Here's the rest of the config:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71289 1) Try switching the Docker Compose v2 option ON; 2) or add this environment variable to the PHP Interpreter : `COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1`

Comment: Thanks, the environment var fixed it..if you want you can answer and I'll accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Speaking in general** (from the [docker-compose exec docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_exec/)):

> Commands are by default allocating a TTY, so you can use a command such as docker-compose exec web sh to get an interactive prompt.

To disable this behavior, you and JetBrains/PhpStorm devs could use `-T` flag to disable pseudo-tty allocation when executing the command, i.e.:

```
docker-compose exec -T web php /path/to/some/file.php
```

Or set the `COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI` environment variable to `1` before running `docker-compose exec`:

```
export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

---

**In case of PHP Interpreter configuration in PhpStorm** (since you do not execute that command yourself), you can set that env variable in the PHP Interpreter settings:

[image]
*(the screenshot is take from [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71289/Running-php-script-with-docker-compose-gives-the-input-device-is-not-a-TTY-when-V2-is-disabled#focus=Comments-27-7080558.0-0))*

Here is PhpStorm ticket to watch after (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71289

[Another option to try](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71289/Running-php-script-with-docker-compose-gives-the-input-device-is-not-a-TTY-when-V2-is-disabled#focus=Comments-27-6989409.0-0):

> I updated my docker and switched from using `docker-compose` to the `docker compose` plugin (by checking **"Use Compose V2"** under "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker | Tools"), and now it works, so it might be a `docker-compose` specific problem.